# Form value submitted at the number of times I clicked on a user

Tags: javascript, jquery

This form value is submitted at the number of times a click on the user is performed.
What I want to do is submit the value to the clicked user, not to the number of times I clicked on a user or various users.

You can run the code here, to see what exactly I'm talking about, you will see the result at the console.

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/sambello/75uysd4c/53/

```
<form>
 <p><strong>USER LIST</strong></p>
 <div class="form-group boxed">
   <div class="input-wrapper">
     <input type="text" id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message...">
     <i class="clear-input">
       <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
     </i>
   </div>
</div>
  <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary rounded">
    <ion-icon name="send">Send</ion-icon>
  </button>
  
</form>
```

```
let users = document.querySelectorAll('.users');
users.forEach(user => {
    user.addEventListener('click', function() {
     
     let query_id = $(this).data("id");
     let query_username = $(this).data("username");
   
    
     let btn_submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
            btn_submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        
            let chat_message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            
            //This value below will display/submit at the number of time you click on the users.
            console.log(query_id);
            console.log(query_username);
            console.log(chat_message)
                
                        // Ajax Goes Below
            
                });
  
  });
    
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't add event listeners on the submit button in the loop. It only needs one listener.

Comment: In general, you should not add event listeners inside other event listeners. As the method name says, the lists are *added*, they don't *replace*. So you get a cascade of calls to the listener, based on the number of times the first event occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a listener to the button, each time you click the user, you should only add one `eventListener` to the button, I have attached a working snippet.

```js
let users = document.querySelectorAll('.users');
let query_id = null;
let query_username = null;

users.forEach(user => {
  user.addEventListener('click', function() {
    query_id = $(this).data("id");
    query_username = $(this).data("username");
  });
});

let btn_submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
btn_submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let chat_message = document.getElementById("message").value;
  console.log(query_id);
  console.log(query_username);
  console.log(chat_message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <strong>USER LIST</strong>
</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="users" data-id="1" data-username="sam"> SAM </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="users" data-id="2" data-username="Tj"> TJ </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="users" data-id="3" data-username="elite"> Elite </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<form>
  <div class="form-group boxed">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="text" id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message...">
      <i class="clear-input">
        <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
      </i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary rounded">
    <ion-icon name="send">Send</ion-icon>
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a radio button for each user. So, you can select only one of the users if you give all the `<input>` the same name attribute.

If you don't like the look of the radio button you can hide it using CSS.

I added a `e.preventDefault();` to stop the form from submitting here on ST. You can just remove that if you need the form to do a POST request to your backend.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  let user = form.querySelector(`input[name="user"][value="${form.user.value}"]`);
  console.log('Say', form.message.value, 'to', user.dataset.username, form.user.value);
  // print out the data from the form
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  console.log([...formData.entries()].map(el => `${el[0]}: ${el[1]}`).join(';'));
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked~span {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <p><strong>USER LIST</strong></p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="user" value="1" data-username="SAM"/><span>SAM</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="user" value="2" data-username="TJ"/><span>TJ</span></label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="user" value="3" data-username="Elite"/><span>Elite</span></label>
  <label><input type="text" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message..."></label>
  <button class="btn btn-icon btn-primary rounded">
    <ion-icon name="send">Send</ion-icon>
  </button>
</form>
```